# Question about the fundamental group of simplicial complex.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Suppose we have a simplicial complex G that is finite connected.
(1)The fundamental group of G is finite;
(2)The universal cover of G is compact.
Question:
Can (1) implies (2)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the universal cover $p\colon\tilde G\to G$, we have that $p^{-1}(x)$ always has $|\pi_1(G)|$ elements. If you have an open cover of $\tilde G$, project it down to $G$ and take a finite subcover. Then to get an open subcover of $\tilde G$, you will need at most $|\pi_1(G)|$ sets for every set in the finite subcover of $G$.

Comment: $|G|$ should be $|\pi_1(G)|$. The question weirdly uses $G$ to denote the space :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thanks for pointing that out.